# Field Mapping issue

Tags: field-mapping

I am facing a problem with field mapping. The problem is that The Close Date field from the  Reg form is not mapping properly to the Close Date in the converted Opportunity field.

Seems that upon converstion, SFDC is automatically assigning a close date of the last day of the quarter

What should be happening is that the date in the Estimated Close Date of the Deal Reg form should copy over to the Close Date in the Opportunity.

Comment: Field mapping of what process?

Comment: Sounds like a web to lead form

Answer (score 1):

On Lead Conversion, the Opportunity Close Date is automatically set to the end of the fiscal year per the doc.

You can use

1)workflow field updates that set CloseDate

2)write triggers on Opportunity before insert to set value

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and try as I might, I could not set the date directly. It always ended up null, and the Close Date was set as yours is.

What I did was create a string field with no validation and sent it the date field from the web form with the date formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Then in a trigger, I converted this to a date using this code:

```
try {
      d = Date.valueOf(dateString);
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Even though this format is correct as an input date into Salesforce, I was only able to get it to work this way.